# Extending and changing the navbar when the user scrolls down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, hamburger-menu, onepage-scroll

I'm currently working on a project website right now and is a one-page website, and I'm new at Bootstrap 3 so I'm still using some start-up templates. The issue I'm having trouble right now is that I don't know how to put an effective but complicated hamburger menu that the client wants:

- when the user is on the home page or the header/carousel, the hamburger menu alone should be on a transparent nav background on the upper right of the screen (not on the edge).
- this header hamburger menu from the header should hide or just be fixed upside when you scroll down a bit.
- when you scroll down AFTER the header, the intended black nav bar should appear, fixed on top, which should extend the small navbar earlier and then become a full screen 100% width bar with the hamburger menu on the right side and company logo on the left side.
- when the hamburger menu is clicked, a navigation box on the right side of the screen should appear.

This is my HTML:

```
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">Navigation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">People</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm currently using a Bootstrap 3 standard template because I wanted to learn more about it before moving to 4. This is my CSS:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3276b1;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}
.btn-primary .badge {
  color: #428bca;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

This is all I'm working with right now for the menu. I would have wanted to create new classes for those stuff so I won't rely on the Bootstrap template and I can edit it asap without messing all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is a sidebar with some scrolling effects. You will have to use some javaScript to achieve this. I don't know the details of exactly how it is done, but I can give you some resources which will help you achieve that.

1. Make a transparent navbar with hamburger menu. (Code given below)

```css
.navcolor{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navcolor  mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Works</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">People</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

2. Create the sidebar. Follow this blog post to achieve that 
   https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar
3. Add the scrolling effects. See this code on codepen.
   https://codepen.io/sonorangirl/pen/XmRBjq

I'm sure you can combine all the above steps to achieve what you want. All the best !

Comment: Thank you for this, the codepen really helped me :)